# Error occuring while sending test mail using flask-mail

Tags: python, email, flask, flask-mail

I am basically building a flask web app which takes codeforces user id and returns user info
i am trying to add flask-mail functionality into it but it displays the

error:

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

The error is in the mail.send(msg) line

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,redirect,request
from flask_mail import Mail,Message
import requests
import json
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'testdev582@gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'hardik1234'
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
#print(app.config.update(mail_settings))
#app.config.update(mail_settings)
mail = Mail(app)

@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        email_id = request.form.get('email-id')
        msg = Message("test",sender=app.config.get("MAIL_USERNAME"),recipients=[email_id])
        mail.send(msg)
        print(email_id)
        #print(username)
        url = 'http://codeforces.com/api/user.info?handles=' + username
        wvurl = 'http://codeforces.com/api/contest.list?gym=false'
        resp = requests.get(url)
        r = requests.get(wvurl)
        if resp and r:
            user_data = json.loads(resp.text)['result']
            contest_data = json.loads(r.text)['result']
            for contest in contest_data:
                if contest['phase'] == 'BEFORE':
                    break
            print(contest['name'])
            return render_template('show.html',user_data = user_data,contest_data = contest)
        else:
            print("Error in getting response")
            return render_template('index.html')
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Can you post the whole traceback?

Comment: Have you enabled allow [less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1) on your google account?

Comment: @TechatTheSparksFoundation Yes i had done that.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use os.environ

example:

```
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER', 'my@email.com')
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS', 'mypassword')
```

or set environment variables
windows:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IolxqkL7cD8
linux:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5iWhQWVXosU

Answer (score -1):

You can try to check `email_id` if it is wrong.

I was just wrong there.

Comment: Simple "here try this" answers should be a comment. So the answer section is kept clean.

Comment: @gerdadiegandalfziege I knew that but I don't have 50 reputation to comment. I only want to help others to solve the problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30968451)